# Laravel 5.0 blade template and count() conditions

Tags: laravel, count, laravel-blade

I've a collection (tasks) and I want to count inside may blade template only completed tasks.

Ex.
Total tasks = 7

Total completed tasks = 2

Total in progress tasks = 5

I try

```
{{ count($tasks->completed = 100) }}
```

And it works, but if I try

```
{{ count($tasks->completed < 100) }}
```

I got an error.

Any help?

Sorry, I'm a newbie on laravel.

(laravel 5.0)

**UPDATE**

I need to show something like:

Completed (2) / in progress (5).

In my controller I've:

```
public function index()
{
    $tasks = Task::All();
    $completed = $tasks->where('completed', 100);
    //I dunno how...
    $inprogress = ...;
    return view('pages.projects', compact('projects', 'tasks', 'completed', 'inprogress'));
}
```

In the db, the tasks table have a 'completed' (integer) column that I use to check the status of the task (0% to 100%, 100% is completed).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't think you are using the correct way to do this. You are doing a count and compare in one function.

### Comparing in blade

```
@if($tasks->completed->count() == 100)
    <p>This is shown if its 100</p>
@else
    <p>This is shown if its not 100</p>
@endif
```

Or this one:

```
@if($tasks->completed->count() < 100)
    <p>This is shown if its smaller than 100</p>
@else
    <p>This is shown if its 100 or bigger</p>
@endif
```

### (Update:) Filtering collection and counting in blade:

```
$tasks = Task::all();
$completed = $tasks->where('completed', 100);
$inprogress = $tasks->filter(function ($task) {
    return $task['completed'] < 100; // Or $task->completed if its an object
});

return view('pages.projects', compact('projects', 'tasks', 'completed', 'inprogress'));
```

Display the count in your blade:

```
<p>{{ $completed->count() }} completed</p>
<p>{{ $inprogress->count() }} in progress</p>
```

Comment: No, I need to show something like: Completed (2) / in progress (5). I need to count...

Comment: Can you add some more information in your openings post? Like your task model + relations, and how do you retrieve your tasks in the controller?