# Laravel - Count number of rows table on the other file.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two pages. I want to count the number of data row table on the second page how can I do that?

Here I have

```
@php echo count($clients); @endphp
```

My two pages have the same variable `$clients`. I have no clue how to count the other page rows table.

Comment: What do you mean by "other page"? Is the same controller? Is a nested view?

Comment: Yes sir the same controller i have two blade.php in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Summer i found some helpful links for you, please check they will help you:

[Laravel 5.0 blade template and count() conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937480/laravel-5-0-blade-template-and-count-conditions)

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/eloquent-how-to-get-the-row-count

[How to count table column values and print in blade file laravel 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52476537/how-to-count-table-column-values-and-print-in-blade-file-laravel-5-6)